# Gulp duplicates destination but adding a period

Tags: git, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

I'm getting strange behaviour with a gulp process.

It's fairly simple - it concats a number of javascript files and places the output into a file. But, it duplicates the output to another folder which is creating problems with my GIT repository. When I delete the rogue folder `js2.` it also deletes the correct folder `js2`

Here's my gulpfile

```
var targetJs = './public/js2';

// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('application', function () {
return gulp.src([
    bowerSource + '/modernizr/modernizr.js',
    bowerSource + '/selectivizr/selectivizr.js',
    bowerSource + '/moment/moment.js',
    bowerSource + '/jquery-validate/dist/jquery.validate.js',
    bowerSource + '/blockui/jquery.blockUI.js',
    bowerSource + '/select2/select2.js',

])
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(concat('application.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(targetJs))
    .pipe(rename('application.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(targetJs));
```

});

This then produces the following:

```
js2/application.js
js2/application.min.js
```

Exactly as expected

I then also have:

```
js2./application.js
js2./application.min.js
```

I have a similar task - exactly the same but it does not behave the same way. This also creates the duplicate on another machine

When I delete the rogue folder `js2.` it also deletes the correct folder `js2`

I'm not sure what the problem is - how can i resolve?

Comment: Sounds like a link is being created, but I can't see how based on your code.  Is there more to your gulpfile.js?  What OS are you running?